# Project abc.exe raised exception class EListError with message 'List index out of bounds (0)' in dxBar.pas file

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-7, vcl, delphi-xe4

I am migrating an old Delphi 7 code to Delphi XE4. I am using DevExpress 13.1 in Delphi XE4 application and using `DevExpress` `ExpressBars` feature. My Delphi 7 application is using an older version of `DevExpress` having `ExpressBars 5`.

In dxBar.pas (`C:\Program Files (86)\DevExpress VCL\ExpressBar\Sources\dxBar.pas`) in Delphi XE4 environment, at line

```
Result := ItemLinks.VisibleItems[0].Control.Height;
```

I am getting a runtime error

```
Project abc.exe raised exception class EListError with message 'List index out of bounds (0)'
```

while same is working fine in `dxBar.pas` with Delhi 7 environment. I don't know what change to make here? Is the change related to index 0 as index in newer Delphi versions start from 1? Its my guess only.

Comment: since "visibleItems" is the property of dx bar and not the array or anything - language changes can have no influence on it, it is totalyl in DevExpress hands.

However DevExpress components suffer very heavy refactorings from version to version. We had to move from Delphi 2006 to XE2 and we had to reintroduce some older methods and properties to be able to use our code. So the things that could change are either the logic behind ExpressBar or the form itself. Check if during migration those items were not deleted and still are present. Is they are - then check that count of visible items >0

Comment: Also search DevExpress forum about that and ExpressBar changelogs - there maybe somethign written about proper migration path and maybe behind logic changes about VisibleItems property

Comment: No, indexes did not change from being zero based for containers like `TList`, `TStringList`, or dynamic arrays. They're all still zero based. (The only thing that is changing is strings being zero based going forward, and at this time that only affects the mobile compilers in XE5, although the Windows and OSX platforms can also optionally use zero-based strings as well using functionality in `TStringHelper`.) The DevEx forums should have info on compatibility changes between versions; this is a vendor-specific question that should probably be asked there instead of here.

Comment: @KenWhite i bet that is either absolutely custom property or one derived from TCollection. But a lean to a former hypothesis. So i think there is no pre-defined Delphi class having direct relation to this

Comment: @Arioch'The: I didn't say anything about it being a standard Delphi class. The question asked "Is the change related to index 0 as index in newer Delphi versions start from 1?", and the answer to that question is "No, not in Delphi." What DevEx did I have no idea about, but I'd highly doubt their code changed from 0 to 1 based indexes either; it makes no sense for them to have done so.

Comment: DevEx code tends to keep Delphi-7 compatibility, so they ignore almost all the new features in Delphi language or RTL/VCL, they even ignore for-in loops introduced in Delphi 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this code:

```
Result := ItemLinks.VisibleItems[0].Control.Height;
```

and this error:

```
List index out of bounds (0)
```

That error tells you that there is no item with index `0`. The list uses zero-based indexing and so the conclusion is that there are no visible items.

Comment: Correct, your VisibleItems is NIL. You'll have to trace in the debugger to find out why.

Comment: @JanDoggen `VisibleItems is NIL` why do you think so ? Judging by error message, i am pretty sure it is not.